# Creating Cache programatically in DataGrid Server

Tags: datagrid, infinispan

I was looking for some documentation to create cache programatically using API, I could see APIs only for Embedded Cache. Non of the documents mentioned about Remote Cache and no where I found this cannot be done too. Can you please let me know if I can create cache programatically on the Cache Server? If so can you please provide link to some of the available document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, unless you want to go through the Server Management API (see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API).
We will be adding remote cache management in Infinispan 9.1